# .NET Core Web API: multiple [FromBody]?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am converting code that was written in ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core MVC. While I was converting the code, I encountered a problem. We used a method that has multiple parameters like this:

```
[HttpPost]                                                      
public class Search(List<int> ids, SearchEntity searchEntity)           
{   
  //ASP.NET MVC                                                                   
}
```

But when coding this in .NET Core, the `ids` parameter is `null`.

```
[HttpPost]                                                      
public class Search([FromBody]List<int> ids,[FromBody]SearchEntity searchEntity)           
{   
  //ASP.NET Core MVC                                                                   
}
```

When I place the `ids` parameter in the `SearchEntity` class, there is no problem. But I have lots of methods that are written like this. What can I do about this problem?

Comment: Can only have one FromBody as the body can only be read once

Comment: where is `ids` coming from. body or URL

Comment: Are you using MVC (posts from "Views") or WebAPI (http post requests from Ajax/JavaScript)? `[FromBody]` is only there to deserialize json (or any other formatter that is configured such as xml). For MVC posts you'd need `[Bind("Value, OtherValue", Prefix="searchEntity"]` or something like that if your data is post in the format of `id=1&id=2&id=3&searchEntity.Value=abc123&searchEntity.OtherValue=xyz`

Comment: Requests from MVC come as `multipart/form-data` and is in similar format to the url query => `key=value&key2=value2&key3=value3` where Webapi requests are usually an xml or json in the payload with `application/json` or `application/xml` mime-type

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to have all parameters used for searching in your `SearchEntity` class?  If the `ids` parameter is used for querying or filtering then include a property for it in `SearchEntity`.

Comment: @Nkosi  **ids** parameter comes from body.

Comment: You can use custom model binding to do bind multiple parameters. For example:

https://evolpin.wordpress.com/2019/02/09/posting-javascript-types-to-mvc-6-in-net-core-using-ajax/#custom-model-binding

Comment: The default for Model Binding is to bind complex parameters from the body of the request. However, only one parameter per action may be bound from body.

So you need to either

    Combine them into one class that just wraps / holds both parameters as properties - and have them bound from the body (as one object)
    Decide which to bind from the body, and which from the route or the query and add the attributes [FromRoute] or [FromQuery] to one, and [FromBody] to the other.

Answer (score 21):

Can only have one `FromBody` as the body can only be read once

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

> There can be at most one parameter per action decorated with `[FromBody]`. The ASP.NET Core MVC run-time delegates the responsibility of reading the request stream to the formatter. Once the request stream is read for a parameter, it's generally not possible to read the request stream again for binding other `[FromBody]` parameters.

MVC Core is stricter on how to bind model to actions. You also have to explicitly indicate where you want to bind the data from when you want to customize binding behavior.

Comment: Before core, I was able to create a custom class to handle multiple parameters by caching the relevant part of the request stream. But with core the analogous code won't fire without `[FromBody]` so this solution no longer works. So annoying.

Answer (score 11):

I have used a solution where multiple parameters are sent as [FromBody] using a tuple:

```
[HttpPost]                                                      
public class Search([FromBody](List<int> ids, SearchEntity searchEntity) parameters)
{   
  //ASP.NET Core MVC                                                                   
}
```

Comment: the downside is that this kind of model is not resolved in swagger...

Comment: @Phil what is the JSON you submit that gets that tuple to be non-null?  I tried it and all my tuple values are null.

Comment: @VladL this is true, unfortunately

Comment: I am not sure. I think it was as follows:

{ ("Item1" : Value, "Item2" : Value) }

Unfortunately, I no longer have access to the code or the application (have changed jobs), but as far as I can remember, it was something like that.

Comment: I checked it and it also did not work for me unfortunately. (ASP NET 7)