# How do I do an AJAX POST call with 2 parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET Core and I have a method in a Controller that looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult RegisterAdmin([FromBody]Admin newAdmin, [FromBody]string password)
{
    IActionResult result;
    ....
}
```

I then have an AJAX call like this:

```
const admin = {
    username: $("#username").val()
};

const password = $("#password").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "/admin/registeradmin",
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ admin, password })
})
```

The RegisterAdmin method is triggered but they are always null. I know I can put them in 1 object, but I need to make it work like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core Web API: multiple \[FromBody\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552702/net-core-web-api-multiple-frombody)

Comment: It doesn't directly but it did inform me that I can't have multiple [FromBody]. Now I am wondering if what I want to do is still possible in ASP.NET Core/

Answer (score 1):

convert two variables into an object

```
var params = new Object();
params.username = $("#username").val();
params.password = $("#password").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "/admin/registeradmin",
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(params)
})
```

Comment: for me it worked without JSON.stringify (i.e. just sending the `params` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object like this:

```
// Assuming you have

// an object:
const admin = {
    username: $("#username").val(),
};

// a string:
const password = $("#password").val();

// an whatever else...

// Create a formdata
let dataToBeSent = new formData();

// Append your things. It's a key/value pair.
dataToBeSent.append("admin", admin);
dataToBeSent.append("password", password);

$.ajax({
    url: "/admin/registeradmin",
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: dataToBeSent
})
```

Use the keys on server side to retreive the values.

Comment: Yep, I know I can do that but as I mentioned in my question "I know I can put them in 1 object, but I need to make it work like this".

Comment: You can send ONE set of data. You can structure it as you which.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean something like: const admin = {
    newAdmin: {username: $("#username").val()},
    password: $("#password").val()
}; If not, can you write an example of what you mean?

Comment: mmmph. That would just be the same object I suggested you to send, wrapped in a `newAdmin` property of the sent object. ... So no big change. I think your challenge is to retreive it on server side. that `...([FromBody]Admin newAdmin, [FromBody]string password)` looks weird... ------- I would try : `...([FromBody]string username, [FromBody]string password)`

Comment: I found out you can't have multiple [FromBody], also I need the first one to be an object because there's more than just username in that object. And then I need the password separated, because I can't put a Password field in the object (not because I can't put technically, more of I can't put because I was requested not to).

Comment: I have this other suggestion about formData... I edited. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Youn need map admin object same name with parameter name `data: JSON.stringify({ newPassword: admin, password })`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/admin/registeradmin",
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ newPassword: admin, password })
})
```

Comment: I gather you meant newAdmin instead of newPassword, so I tried this out: data: JSON.stringify({ newAdmin: admin, password }) but still, all params were null.